# Storing JFrame output into a String in the Main Program

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

It seems to me that so far, everything that happens within JFrame stays within JFrame. (Probably should have gotten into JavaFX instead of Swing)

Let's say you have a JFrame Class (gui_frame) that utilizes JButtons with a nested class named HandlerClass that implements ActionListener, as shown below:

```
public class gui_frame extends JFrame {
    private JButton button1;
    public gui_frame() {
         super("Title");
         setLayout(new FlowLayout());

         button1 = new JButton("Hello");
         add(button1);

         HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
         button1.addActionListener(handler);
    }

   private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          //insert code here
          }
   }
}
```

And then you have the main code, which calls upon this gui_frame class.

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //insert some unrelated code here

        gui_frame gf = new gui_frame();
        gf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gf.setSize(400,75);
        gf.setVisible(true);

        String button_name;
        //insert some code that uses button_name           
    }
}
```

Essentially, I'm trying to store the name of the button in the JFrame class gui_frame (in this case "Hello"), AFTER BEING CLICKED, into the String button_name in the main class, **during run time.**

Is this possible? What do I have to insert into the actionPerformed method in the gui_frame, in order to make this happen?

Comment: *"It seems to me that so far, everything that happens within JFrame stays within JFrame."* Wrong! It depends on the code. A `JFrame` ain't like Las Vegas. Those code difference start with `public class gui_frame extends JFrame {` **Don't extend `JFrame`** unless *changing* functionality of its methods. Just use an instance of a frame. Put a button inside it that has an action listener that is within the scope of the `button_name` attribute & update the attribute on action performed. *"(Probably should have gotten into JavaFX instead of Swing)"* No, better to learn how to program..

Comment: .. you'd have just as much trouble using Java-FX otherwise. As an aside, a frame is non-modal, so `button_name` with still be uninitialised when `//insert some code that uses button_name ` is reached. You are 'coding by magic' here. That never works.

Comment: Thanks for the modal explanation. I'll try using JDialog from now on, if this is an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways that you could do this:

1. implement the ActionListener as a lambda in the main class (btw, that should be capitalized, i.e. "Main"),  and pass the lambda to the gui_frame class (again, that should be "GuiFrame"), and have the GuiFrame class apply the listener to the button
2. create an interface for the GuiFrame class to use to notify the Main class that the button has been clicked (and the name of the button). Have the Main class implement that interface, and then pass the instance of Main to the GuiFrame class. Then have the GuiFrame's ActionListener call the method in the Main class' interface to notify it.
3. Store the name of the last clicked button in the GuiFrame class, and have the Main class ask for it when it needs it (if it doesn't need to know when the button is clicked).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Will try all of them to see which is more efficient.